# am I using </table> wrong?

Tags: html, css, sql, outlook, html-email

`I am creating an automatic mail using de msdb function but when the sql is converted to HTML and send in outlook the table data rows keep adding and outlook crashes.
while only one row is expected, as shows when I just run the query.
This is what I have at this moment

```
DECLARE @tableHTML NVARCHAR(max) = '';

SET @tableHTML =
'<h1>Picking en Rework</h1>' +
'<table border="1">' +
'<tr>' +
'<th>Order ETA</th>' +
'<th>To be Picked</th>' +
'<th>Rework Actions</th>' +
'<th>Destination Plts req order-line</th>' +
'<th>Destination Plts Req Total</th>' +
'<th>Reworked Plts On Stock</th>' +
'<th>Plts Left To Rework Order-Line</th>' +
'<th>Plts Left To Rework total</th>' +
'</tr>' +    
CAST
(   
( 
SELECT
                            
td = coalesce(vOuttakeOrderHeaders_2057.[ETA], ''),  '', 
td = coalesce([To be Picked],  ''), '',             
td = coalesce(vReworkReq_2057.[Rework Actions],  ''),  '',
td = coalesce(vReworkReq_2057.[Destination Plts Req Order-Line],  
''),'',
td = coalesce(vReworkReq_2057.[Destination Plts Req total],  ''),  '',
td = coalesce(vReworkReq_2057.[Reworked Plts On Stock],  ''),  '',
td = coalesce(vReworkReq_2057.[Plts Left To Rework Order-Line], ''),  
'',
td = coalesce(vReworkReq_2057.[Plts Left To Rework total],  ''),  ''
                                                                
FROM [dbo].[vMailReworkPicking_2057], vOuttakeOrderDetails_2057
left join vOuttakeOrderHeaders_2057 on 
vOuttakeOrderDetails_2057.iOrderHeaderSysID = 
vOuttakeOrderHeaders_2057.iOrderHeaderSysID

left join vReworkReq_2057 on vOuttakeOrderDetails_2057.Article = 
vReworkReq_2057.Article
left join vMailReworkPicking_2057 on vOuttakeOrderHeaders_2057.[ETA] = 
vMailReworkPicking_2057.[Order ETA]

Where 
vOuttakeOrderHeaders_2057.[Order Type] like 'outtake'
and DisposedQuantity < TargetQuantity 
and RestPick > 0

ORDER BY vOuttakeOrderHeaders_2057.[ETA] DESC
FOR XML PATH('tr'), type) as nvarchar(max)) +
'</table>';

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'test123',
@recipients = 'email',
@subject = 'Picking & Rework',
@body = @tableHTML,
@body_format = 'HTML';`
```

Comment: `FROM [dbo].[vMailReworkPicking_2057], vOuttakeOrderDetails_2057` this is a cross join, also there is no where clause. Both can lead to multiple rows instead of one row.

Comment: I changed edited the code as to what it is now. But now I get " Error converting data type varchar to numeric."  Because of this line:
td = coalesce([To be Picked],  ''), '',  thats supposed to be a numeric value

Comment: It looks like you are generating `</table>`  twice: after the header and after the full table contents. You want only the one at the end - it is the end of the `<table>` element

Comment: yes I forgot to take that one out of this code, but it was already out of my original one

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).